# Adding Web Part with Stapling Feature

Tags: sharepoint

I have a problem adding web part to a blog default.aspx with stapling Feature. this is my code:

```
try
{
SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
//SPFile thePage = web.RootFolder.Files["default.aspx"];
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx",PersonalizationScope.Shared);
```

.......

but every time I try to get default.aspx it says that file does not exist. Anyone can help me on this, because all the articles about adding web parts with features while site is creating (Stapling Feature) point on this kind of solution. Is there anything special?

Answer (score 0):

Are you activating your feature in a publishing web? It may not have a default.aspx in the root then, but in /Pages/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you the staple a feature the feature is activated before all the content is added.  The feaure has to have that page as bart of the feature, then you should be able to add the web part.